# Combine 2 columns of a KStream as map or array in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have a stream as below

```
CREATE STREAM sample AS
SELECT
    p1.grade,
    p1.val,
    p2.parameters
FROM Parent1 p1
JOIN Parent2 p2
ON
p1.rule = p2.rule;
```

How can I combine `p1.val` and `p2.parameter` in other next stream may be like `[{ "val" : p1.val, "params": p2.parameters}]`?
OR
Is it possible in the above stream itself? Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. As you have two inputs the first question is if `Parent1`/`Parent2` are STREAMs or TABLESs? You say "CREATE STREAM" but your join does not contain a WITHIN clause, so it's not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build either an array containing a single struct, or a map. You can do this using array, struct and map constructors:

```sql
-- create an array:
ARRAY[1,2,3]

-- create a map:
MAP('key1':= 10, 'key2':= 20)

-- create a struct:
STRUCT('field1':= 10, 'field2':= 'bob')
```

So to get the output of `[{ "val" : p1.val, "params": p2.parameters}]` you might try:

```sql
CREATE STREAM sample AS
SELECT
    ARRAY[STRUCT(
    'val' := p1.val,
    'params' := p2.parameters
    )] AS COL0
FROM Parent1 p1
JOIN Parent2 p2
ON
p1.rule = p2.rule;
```

Or to output as a map, (which requires all the types to match):

```sql
CREATE STREAM sample AS
SELECT
    MAP(
    'val' := p1.val,
    'params' := p2.parameters
    ) AS COL0
FROM Parent1 p1
JOIN Parent2 p2
ON
p1.rule = p2.rule;
```

Or to output as a struct:

```sql
CREATE STREAM sample AS
SELECT
    STRUCT(
    'val' := p1.val,
    'params' := p2.parameters
    ) AS COL0
FROM Parent1 p1
JOIN Parent2 p2
ON
p1.rule = p2.rule;
```

Note: these constructors were introduced a release or three ago. If you get compiler errors you may need to upgrade to a later ksqlDB version.